# write Java Script timestamp to input field

Tags: input, timestamp, hidden

I want to write timestamp generated by java script to a hidden form input field.The following code writes the timestamp to a paragraph(p element) but does not write to the input element.

> It writes to one element but fails to do so to another element.

Can anybody throw light on this behaviour of the script?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">pkj</p>
<input id="ts" type="time" name="ts"></input>
<script>
    var oD = new Date();
    document.getElementById("ts").innerHTML = oD.getTime();//**FAILS**
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = oD.getTime();//**SUCCEEDS**
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` by definition is an empty element, meaning there is no innerHTML, it has no permitted content. And there is no need for a closing tag (`</input>`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

You can change the property "value", a sort of default input by

```
document.getElementById("ts").value = oD.getTime();
```

Or you could add a label like

```
<label id="label">xyz</label><input id="ts" type="time" name="ts">
```

and change it with

```
document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = oD.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks JosefScript !,

Comment: And, btw, still no need for a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

As per your advice I changed the input element's attribute from "**innerHTML**" to "**

"**value**" as shown in code below.It is working fine now.
The issue is SOLVED.

thanks

Jayk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo" > </p>
        <input id="ts" type="time" name="ts" value=""></input>
        <script>
           var oD = new Date();
           document.getElementById("ts").value = oD.getTime();//**SUCCEEDS**
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = oD.getTime();//**SUCCEEDS**
           var t=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```